# how to provide request_url with specification while web scraping using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm on the web page with the url=x 
The url of that particular web page doesn't change after giving my preferences(like selecting options,..) or after clicking the button on that web page.

Problem:

Before performing the above mentioned actions i will not be displayed with any data; but post actions the web page displays the data.

Context:

I'm trying to scrape data from a web page using python 
And i'm struck at providing the request_url with the above mentioned specification
if i'm providing request_url=x it is fetching no data because i have provided no specifications

How to provide those specifications while requesting with the url?

kindly address the specification of pressing the button also

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to scrape data through real navigation actions, like filling form data and clicking on buttons and/or posting some data, considering whatever javascript scripts contains in the page, but you don't have the specifications to post the data.

My approach would be automating a real browser using [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html), finding the button via `xpath` or id and calling a `click` function to it.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# Assume the button has the ID "submit" :)
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
```